# Is there a way I can skip by value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I'm try to skip values continuously in my MySQL table, for example:
I have a table here

```
time      value
t1        val1
t2        val2
t3        val3
t4        val4
t5        val5
```

And the result that i need is

```
time      value
t1        val1
t3        val3
t5        val5
```

Hopefully you guys understand my problem
Similarly I need to skip by 2 values,3,4 and 5.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip"? If you want to "skip by 2 values 3,4, and 5" (which are already three, or did I count them wrong?), why is there `val3` and `val5` in the expected result?

Comment: As I see you skip positionally, even records, not "by value"...

Comment: @Nico I think the concept is called skip counting I guess, that's what I'm trying to achieve. My questioning skills are 0 sorry about that.

Comment: @Akina Yes, I'm not only skipping values but even the records.

Comment: Can you please provide example values? Is the difference between two time(stamps?) always the same?

Comment: If so then see **sticky bit**'s solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the order is defined by `time`, in MySQL 8+ you can use `row_number()` to assign a number to each row ordered by `time` and then pick only the rows with an odd number using the modulo operator `%`.

```
SELECT x.time,
       x.value
       FROM (SELECT t.time,
                    t.value,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.time) rn) x
       WHERE rn % 2 = 1;
```

Comment: @Akina: Yes, that would work in MySQL. But it's clearer to be verbose here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use IN statement

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NOT IN(values);

values=(2,4,....);

You will get results , and in values you can pass array as you don't want value

Comment: I'm sorry but i made a mistake with the question. I'm skipping the row itself by trying to employ skip counting method.